# Cómo puedo unir cadenas en Excel?

Tags: excel

necesito formar una cadena en excel que quede de la siguiente forma:

(1, 'EL BATAN')

Tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que en la columna derecha se aparezca el texto
(1, 'EL BATAN') y así sucesivamente. Pero con parentésis y comillas

Gracias

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? No esperarás que lo hagan por ti. Saludos

Answer (score 5):

Usando la función [CONCAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) (creo que es CONCATENAR en español):

```
=CONCAT("(1,'",A1,"')")
```

Puedes concatenar N elementos, incluyendo cadenas que puedes definir entre comillas dobles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado se parece a lo que buscas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos desde El Batán xD

Comment: Que coincidencia. Justo El Batán

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que necesitas es que el número sea consecutivo también y se vaya incrementando, entonces:

`="("&FILA()-1&", '"&A2&"')"`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto solo funcionará si tus datos empiezan en A2. PAra la parte del número, el truco está en `FILA()-1`. Tienes que poner un cálculo que te devuelva 1 en la primera fila de tus datos. Por ejemplo, si tus datos empiezan en la fila 6, tendrías que poner `FILA()-5`, si empiezan en la fila 10, tendrías que poner `FILA()-9` y así.

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Tambien se puede hacerlo con el &

="1,'"&a1&"')"